# Touch function not working

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
local Gin2
local function Gin ( event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
      Gin2 = display.newImage("PNGs/Sprite/Gin")
        Gin2.x = _H
        Gin2.y = _W

    end
    return true
end
  Runtime:addEventListener("touch", Gin )
```

Hello, so I've been trying to figure out this for some time, but with with no success. So as may guess the idea is to spawn an image by touching.Should I define the object that will be touch?

Comment: you cannot add touch to a runTIme listener. Touch can be used only for the display objects.  https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/enterFrame/name.html

Comment: Actually @KumarKS you can add a touch to a runtime listener. as stated at the docs: https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/events/detectEvents/index.html#functionvstable BUT it will be a Table Listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a code for you to use. When you want to spawn an object via **touch listener** *(Either Runtime event or a single event)* you can use **event.x** and **event.y** to determine the touch point of the user. Below is the code.

**NOTE:** I made *gin* as a **array** for future use of your spawned object

```
local val = 1
local gin = {}

local spawnObject = function(event)

  if(event.phase == "ended") then

    gin[val] = display.newImage("PNGs/Sprite/Gin")
    gin[val].x = event.x
    gin[val].y = event.y 

    val = val + 1

  end



end

 Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", spawnObject )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the 'functional listener' form and for 'touch' event you should not be using Runtime.

In your case, you need to change Runtime to the object that 'is to be touched'. I guess what you want to do is to move the image once it is touched.

so, firstly move

```
Gin2 = display.newImage("PNGs/Sprite/Gin")
```

up and out the function. then change Runtime to Gin2.